# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Xcode debugger when stepping over?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

Learning how to code on Mac OS X for me is mainly about familiarizing myself with Xcode and I have this weird problem:

when I debug code and I move the debugger arrowhead from one line to another, I always get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Consider the following example:

```
    int main (int argc, char** argv)
    {
        printf("Test1\n");
        printf("Test2\n");
        printf("Test3\n");
    }
```

I start stepping over line by line and I can see the output strings being displayed in the Output window. When the code reaches third printf() statement, I take the green arrowhead and drag it back to the first printf() statement. What I woud expect is that the execution would resume on this line, but after stepping over, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in __vfprintf:

```
    EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1, address = 0x6)
```

I have tried several similar dummy examples with the same result. I feel like missing something too obvious to notice it.

Regards,

Ondrej

Comment: your example code should work, I think it also shouldn't produce the symbol: __vfprintf, are you using c++? how did you set up your project?

Comment: This is plain C, I have set up the project as console app, with defaults. Xcode 4.6.2. The sample works - three lines of text are printed. I only get the exception when I try to mess with the flow of execution using the green debugger arrowhead.

Comment: I don't know, probably run down the general troubleshooting list, hold option- clean build folder... restart Xcode, remove derived data dir... if that fails reinstall Xcode. also try gdb if you are using lldb or visa versa, check that the version launched matches the one in your Xcode bundle.